# how can i group core data objects by date in sections for use in a collectionView

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, header

I am trying to display my collectionView cells in sections with a date header for each section.  ie. the cells are organised by date as in a chat app.  I am storing my data in core data.  Is there an efficient way to organise my core data objects by date in sections?  thank you in advance.

Comment: A fetched results controller...

Comment: i thought that only worked with a tableView?  I will look closer at it.  Thanks

Comment: why did you think that?

Comment: Not sure. Just always mentioned in that context.